# How to document an object containing objects with ESDoc

Tags: javascript, jsdoc, esdoc

I am attempting to document an object containing other objects in a class constructor using ESDoc (similar syntax to JSDoc).

```
/** 
 * A description.
 * @type {object}
 */
this.materialProperties = {
    paper: {
        roughness: 0.5,
        metalness: 0.0,
        reflectivity: 0.5
    },
    wood: {
        roughness: 0.5,
        metalness: 0.0,
        reflectivity: 0.5
    },
    metal: {
        roughness: 0.5,
        metalness: 0.5,
        reflectivity: 0.9,
        clearCoat: 1,
        clearCoatRoughness: 0
    },
    glass: {
        roughness: 0.5,
        metalness: 0.5,
        reflectivity: 0.9,
        clearCoat: 1,
        clearCoatRoughness: 0,
        opacity: 0.5,
        transparent: true
    }
}
```

However, when I run the documentation that line is marked as undocumented and nothing shows up in the generated documentation.

[image]

What can I do to document this line? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that there is a bug in ESDoc where if you have an object containing objects, the line AFTER that won't be documented no matter what you do.

I have created an issue in ESDoc here:

https://github.com/esdoc/esdoc/issues/549